# Get the result of Observable Bool variables in another Observable Bool variable?

Tags: ios, swift, observable

let's say we have this piece of code:

```
var clientLinesLoaded:Bool = Bool() {
        didSet{
            print(clientLinesLoaded)
            if(clientLinesLoaded == true){
                print("->->->->->  clientLinesLoaded")
            }else{
                print("->->->->-> error loading...")
            }
        }
    }

var clientDatasLoaded:Bool = Bool() {
        didSet{
            print(clientDatasLoaded)
            if(clientDatasLoaded == true){
                print("->->->->->  clientLinesLoaded")
            }else{
                print("->->->->-> error loading...")
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to **fire another didSet when both variables** are set to **"true"**

So this is what i was thinking ...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


var loaderMustDisappear:Bool = Bool(self.clientLinesLoaded && self.clientDatasLoaded) {
            didSet {
                print ("value is: ",loaderMustDisappear)
                if(loaderMustDisappear){
                    print("remove loader")
                    self.cargador.isHidden=true
                }else{
                    print("loading failed, do actions to control")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The first 2 didSets are firing properly when they change it's values.

The problem is what **didSet on loaderMustDisappear is never called**, and i'm not sure why is this happening...

Anyone has deal with some situation like this?

Thanks all!

Comment: The property observer is not called when the default value of the property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why your code will work or not because the `loaderMustDisappear` variable is declared in `viewDidLoad` and you are changing the value of `clientLinesLoaded` and `clientDatasLoaded` from another function.

But you can achieve this using `closures`. Declare a closure in your class :

```
var loaderMustDisappearClosure : (()->())?
```

and in two `Bool` variables:

```
var clientLinesLoaded:Bool = Bool() {
    didSet{
        print(clientLinesLoaded)
        if(clientLinesLoaded == true){
            print("->->->->->  clientLinesLoaded")
            self. loaderMustDisappearClosure?()
        }else{
            print("->->->->-> error loading...")
        }
    }
}

var clientDatasLoaded:Bool = Bool() {
    didSet{
        print(clientDatasLoaded)
        if(clientDatasLoaded == true){
            print("->->->->->  clientLinesLoaded")
            self. loaderMustDisappearClosure?()
        }else{
            print("->->->->-> error loading...")
        }
    }
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad` :

```
self.loaderMustDisappearClosure = {
    if self.clientLinesLoaded && self.clientDatasLoaded {
        print("Disappear Loader")
    }
}

self.clientLinesLoaded = true
self.clientDatasLoaded = true
```

when you will execute this after setting `true` to `clientDatasLoaded` . Disappear loader will print in console. So you can achieve this from anywhere in the class.

Hope this helps what you want to achieve.

Comment: The closure did de trick, but i needed to change self.loaderMustDisappear = { to self. loaderMustDisappearClosure = {

Comment: sorry ... it's copy paste mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your statement `Bool(self.clientLinesLoaded && self.clientDatasLoaded)`, but probably this will never call your variable. Try to set `loaderMustDisappear` inside both variables.
I think the code bellow should work for you:

```
var clientLinesLoaded:Bool = Bool() {
    didSet{
        print(clientLinesLoaded)
        if(clientLinesLoaded == true){
            print("->->->->->  clientLinesLoaded")
        }else{
            print("->->->->-> error loading...")
        }
        loaderMustDisappear = clientLinesLoaded && clientDatasLoaded
    }
}

var clientDatasLoaded:Bool = Bool() {
    didSet{
        print(clientDatasLoaded)
        if(clientDatasLoaded == true){
            print("->->->->->  clientLinesLoaded")
        }else{
            print("->->->->-> error loading...")
        }
        loaderMustDisappear = clientLinesLoaded && clientDatasLoaded
    }
}

var loaderMustDisappear:Bool = Bool() {
    didSet {
        print ("value is: ",loaderMustDisappear)
        if(loaderMustDisappear){
            print("remove loader")
            cargador.isHidden=true
        }else{
            print("loading failed, do actions to control")
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

I created a basic code for easy understanding:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
var var1: Bool = Bool() {
    didSet{
        var12 = var1 && var2
    }
}

var var2: Bool = Bool() {
    didSet{
        var12 = var1 && var2
    }
}
var var12: Bool = Bool() {
    didSet {
        print("var12 is \(var12)")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Testing:
    var1 = true
    var2 = true
    var1 = false
    }
}
```